# How can i used Arduino Serial Port data in if condition and execute code?

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am creating a Arduino project using MQ-2 Gas Sensor and the code is working well and sending data in serial port. but I want to use the data that was received from my Arduino in my if condition to execute some lines of code.
like:
if(Console.ReadLine == ("WARNING!"))
{
I'll insert my code here
}

I tried doing this in my code and it does not run my code.

```
string oneLine = port.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(oneLine);
                        string ArduinoResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (ArduinoResponse == "WARNING!")
                        {
                            I'll insert my function here
                        }
```

Comment: maybe print `ArduinoResponse` to see it

Answer (score 0):

In c and C++ you can't just say  string a == string b. you need to understand that in C and C++ strings are an array of characterss.

To check if 2 strings are equal to eachother you need to use the strcmp function.

So try this

```
string ArduinoResponse = Console.ReadLine();
if (strcmp(ArduinoResponse, "WARNING!") == 0)
{
    I'll insert my function here
}
```

Please refer for more information about strcmp to : https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/